i18n localization in this project
can you help me how can i add i18n localize function to this project? i would like to have a dropdown in the navbar for the languages.
here is the code:
https://github.com/GergoJeles/portfolio_tailwind.git
I would like to have a navbar like here from the flowbite website with the language dropdown.
https://flowbite.com/docs/components/navbar/

Please see Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during your attempt you encounter a specific problem, such as a specific operation producing an error or an unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Additionally... Please see Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.

Make your Default route to be /en and add a simple flag in the html that is an a tag.
and on click it should navigate the user to /es for example.
and build a diffrent html file for the /es so the user goes there on click and change the content language.
